# how to change dimensions of div when form is submitted

Tags: jquery

When I submit a form, I want another object to increase in width and to remain that way. This is what I have:

```
$("form#inputs").submit(function() {
    $(".circles").css("width", "200px");
});
```

When submitted, `.circles` increase in width, but quickly reverts back in a split second. I want them to remain with an increased width, how can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like your page is getting reloaded after the form submission. So do this:

```
$("form#inputs").submit(function (e) {
    $(".circles").css("width", 200);
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: It would prevent the process of submission, no? (just a thought)

Comment: @nicael Yup... But I believe the data is sent via AJAX and OP is not intending to submit in the traditional way.

Answer (score 0):

@Praveen Kumar is correct - if you want to edit an element in your DOM with javascript, you'll need to post your form information using `AJAX`.

If you don't want to use `AJAX`, you can pass a variable back to the page after handling the form which would trigger a class to be added to your `.circles` element.

To send your information via `AJAX` you can simple do the following

#### form.php

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jQuery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="myScript.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<form id="myForm">
    <label for="input1">
        Input 1: <input type="text" name="input1" id="input1">
    </label>
    <label for="input2">
        Input 2: <input type="text" name="input2" id="input2">
    </label>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit My Form">
</form>

<div class="circles">... Some stuff ...</div>

</body>
</html>
```

#### myScript.js

```
$( document ).ready( function() {

    // Listen for our form submit
    $( '#myForm' ).submit( function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); // Stop the form from submitting

        var datastring = $( this ).serialize(); // Serialize our form

        $.ajax({

            url: 'handler.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: datastring,
            success: function() {
                // do whatever i want if the form posts
                $( ".circles" ).css( "width", "200px" );
            },
            error: function() {
                // do whatever i want if there is an error
                $( ".circles" ).css( "color", "red" );
            }

        }); // .ajax

    }); // .submit

}); // document.ready
```

#### handler.php

```
<?php

$input1 = $_POST['input1'];
$input2 = $_POST['input2'];

// do stuff

?>
```